# How can i change the format of my "time elapse" in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to return my time elapsed value in the format mm:ss, but currently it is returning "Sat Dec 30 1899 00:07:08 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)". I only want 07:08 from the string. How can I change the format of one column in an array?

Comment: Please clarify whether your source data is `Date` objects or text strings, and show the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a number of ways to do this, one way is to use a regular expression and `exec()` like so:

```js
const fullDate = 'Sat Dec 30 1899 00:07:08 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)';
const mmss = /\d\d:(\d\d:\d\d)/.exec(fullDate)[1];
console.log(mmss);
```

You can [read up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) more on `exec()` if you like.